# How to create custom dropdownlist with Grouped data in Adobe Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I wish to create a custom dropdown list which shows grouped data. The one having title of (category) sub-data shouldn't be selectable while other ones (names) should be selectable.

Expected output should be something like below data to be shown in Dropdown list

```
Administrators
       John
       David
Users
      Peter
      Steven
      James
Members
Jury
```

[Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TySyF.jpg):
[image]

Comment: I've added `AS3` and `Flash` tags to get your question more noticed. Use the [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57686856/edit) button under tags to do any useful modifications. PS: Show code of your list so far... Then you can get advice about how to adjust your code for listing with groups / categories.

Comment: @VC.One Thank you for the suggestion of editing the question. This is a new requirement from the stakeholders and are asking for developing such dropdownlist.

Comment: _"asking for developing such dropdownlist"_ see: [flex dropdown list tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=flex+dropdown+list+tutorial). We can only help you fix problems in your code. Try something then ask here when stuck.